# Transforming JSON keys and values

Tags: python, json

I have a simple json in python that looks like :

```
{
    "list": [{
            "key1": "value1"
        },
        {
            "key1": "value1"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to transform this to the following json. Any suggestions how I can do it with python without installing additional libraries?

```
{
    "list": [{
        "keys": {
            "name": "key1",
            "value": "value1"
        }
    }, {
        "keys": {
            "name": "key1",
            "value": "value1"
        }
    }]
}
```

Comment: The built-in json module will convert that into the appropriate python data structures through `json.loads()` (assuming that's a string). You can then proceed to manipulate as necessary.

Comment: It's not clear how the input is supposed to relate to the output. For example, what should happen if the innermost dicts in the input have more than one key-value pair?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure from your question if you already have the json read into a variable, or if it is in a file. This is assuming you have it in a variable already:

```
in_json = {
    "list": [{
            "key1": "value1"
        },
        {
            "key2": "value2"
        }
    ]
}

out_json = {"list":[]}
for kd in in_json["list"]:
    sub_kd = {"keys": {}}
    for k,v in kd.iteritems():
        sub_kd["keys"]["name"] = k
        sub_kd["keys"]["value"] = v

    out_json["list"].append(sub_kd)

print(out_json)
```

It just loops through the json making dictionaries to append to the `out_json` dictionary. You could make this print pretty with the json library and also save to file with it

Answer (score 0):

You didn't indicate exactly what contains the JSON data is in, so I've put it all in a string in the example code below and uses the [`json.loads()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load) function to turn it into a Python dictionary. If it's in a file, you can use the module's [`json.load()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load) function instead.

It also make the assume that each sub-JSON object in the `"list"` list consists of only one key/value pair as shown in your question.

The code below changes the deserialized dictionary *in-place* and pretty-prints the result of doing that by using the [`json.dumps()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps) function to reserialize it.

Note that I changed the keys and values in sample input JSON slightly to make it easier to see the correspondence between it and the printed results.

```
import json


json_in = '''
    {
        "list": [
            {
                "key1": "value1"
            },
            {
                "key2": "value2"
            }
        ]
    }
'''

json_data = json.loads(json_in)  # Deserialize.

for i, obj in enumerate(json_data['list']):
    # Assumes each object in list contains only one key, value pair.
    newobj = { 'name': next(iter(obj.keys())),
              'value': next(iter(obj.values()))}
    json_data['list'][i] = {'keys': newobj}

print(json.dumps(json_data, indent=4))  # Reserialize and print.
```

Printed result:

```
{
    "list": [
        {
            "keys": {
                "name": "key1",
                "value": "value1"
            }
        },
        {
            "keys": {
                "name": "key2",
                "value": "value2"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```